# How to use the dbSeeChanges option with OpenRecordset when accessing a SQL Server table that has an IDENTITY column?

Tags: sql-server, vba

```
Private Sub update ()    
   Dim db As Database
   Set db = CurrentDb
   Dim rs As Recordset

   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * From Table", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
   db.Execute ("UPDATE Table SET Path = '" & A.Value & "' WHERE B = '" & B.Value & "'")

   db.Close
End Sub
```

When I got vba access Error 3622 (i.e use the dbSeeChanges option with OpenRecordset when accessing a SQL Server table that has an IDENTITY column) a proposed solution was to add the first line (Set rs=... see above in the coding) which I did but it did not resolve the problem.
Is there another way to avoid this error ?

I am new in coding and would appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I follow the logic in your code... Was the RS always opened, or did you just add it? That code opens a RS, which is never used, then never closes it.  Did you see the article about opening a new DB, then importing the form / code and linking the table, which fixed that error?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I just added the RS to the code. I am not sure I know which article you are referring to  (although I saw 2 other questions related to this problem in this site and one which appears to fix the problem - intend to try that to fix my problem in the meantime). Can you please send the link ?

Comment: So you first got the error on the db.Execute statement? The article I mentioned is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004932/error-3622-you-must-use-the-dbseechanges-option-with-openrecordset-when-access - jiust expand the comments and look at the end.  Here is a better idea: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/53b7ba4e-705c-4505-81cb-b781bc87792d/error-message-using-dbexecute-on-sql-server-must-use-dbseechanges?forum=accessdev - to avoid falling asleep at the keyboard, scroll to bottom and work up. Mentions using "dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges"

Comment: Yes, I had the error on the db.Execute statement hence I now removed the RS (which was only added as a correction) and added the dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges at the end of my db.Execute line. These latter two values are constants. But I know get the following message: Error 3464 Incompatible data type on my db.Execute line. I checked to see if I was passing variable with different data types from my frontend (Access) to my SQL server and corrected the problem but I still have the same error message.

Comment: 1. Did you also try the part of 'OR'ing the options?  2. I assume everything is DAO and nothing is ADO? (I know it is geeky, but I try to always 'Dim' things explicitly so nobody confuses the two.) 3. Is your table name really 'Table'?  Try this: ("UPDATE [Table] SET [Path] = '" & A.Value & "' WHERE [B] = '" & B.Value & "'")

Comment: It works now. The data type mismatch that I had was due to the update statement which had numeric variables so I removed the single quotes. I also put dbFailOnError Or dbSeeChanges. I let the declaration of database as is; I was gettign an error msg when trying to revert to ADODB. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can you post the answer as an answer then please to help other users. In brief the solution was to add the `dbSeeChanges` option to the end of the Execute statement. I believe the method to add the `dbFailOnError` option and Error 3464 are not relevant to the question asked although they might merit separate questions.

Answer (score 7):

Since OP has disappeared - add **dbSeeChanges** to the end of the command (VBA):

```
DBEngine(0)(0).Execute "UPDATE Table SET Path = '" & A.Value & "' WHERE B = '" & B.Value & "'", dbSeeChanges
```

Comment: May also need to set the recordset with Set rs AS DAO.Recordset. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/error-3622-use-dbseechanges-option-with/aad8a589-2297-432f-af32-8ba32b7d3573

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Your link was my answer ```Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("YourThingHere", , RecordsetOptionEnum.dbSeeChanges)```