# Error 3622 Open SQL Server Table with Identity Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

What am I doing wrong? I need to copy one record from the table dbo_customer (and then delete it there) to the table dbo_active_task. But I get an error "Error 3622 - You must use the dbSeeChanges option with OpenRecordset when accessing a SQL Server table that has an IDENTITY column."

```
Dim stSQlIns As String
Dim stSqlD As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

If MsgBox("Copy № " & Me![id].Value, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Moving to the archive ") = vbYes Then

stSQlIns = "INSERT INTO [dbo_new] " _
& "SELECT [dbo_customer].[id], [dbo_customer].[apartment], [dbo_customer].[description], [dbo_customer].[documents], [dbo_customer].[email], [dbo_customer].[first_name], [dbo_customer].[house_number], [dbo_customer].[last_name], [dbo_customer].[middle_name], [dbo_customer].[passport_number_str], [dbo_customer].[passport_number], [dbo_customer].[passport_series], [dbo_customer].[tel_number], [dbo_customer].[street_id], [dbo_active_task].[check_number], [dbo_active_task].[enable], [dbo_active_task].[production_datetime], [dbo_active_task].[production_method], [dbo_active_task].[shedule_datetime], [dbo_active_task].[shedule_end_datetime], [dbo_active_task].[task_desc], [dbo_active_task].[vip], [dbo_active_task].[customer_id], [dbo_active_task].[schedule_person_id], [dbo_active_task].[task_id]" _
& "FROM [dbo_customer], [dbo_active_task] " _
& "WHERE ((([dbo_customer].[id])=" & Me![id].Value & ")) "

stSqlD = "DELETE [dbo_customer].*, [dbo_active_task].* " _
& "FROM [dbo_customer], [dbo_active_task] " _
& "WHERE ((([dbo_customer].[id])=" & Me![id].Value & "))"
Set rs = Me.Recordset
CurrentDb.Execute (stSQlIns)
CurrentDb.Execute (stSqlD)
Me![id].Requery

End If
```

Comment: Please remove the database tags you are not actually using.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486176/how-to-use-the-dbseechanges-option-with-openrecordset-when-accessing-a-sql-serve

Comment: @Nayak I've added this code `CurrentDb.Execute stSQlIns, dbSeeChanges`
`CurrentDb.Execute stSqlD, dbSeeChanges` insted of this `CurrentDb.Execute (stSQlIns)`
`CurrentDb.Execute (stSqlD)` and now it copies the record for many times (I need just one), but not delete it from the table.

Comment: well remove your delete SQL.....

Comment: @Nathan_Sav so how it goes to delete the current record?

Comment: ` but not delete it from the table`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav ok, I've removed DELETE sql, dut it continues to add the record for many times.

Comment: are there many for that ID?  What does just the select bring back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
& "FROM [dbo_customer], [dbo_active_task] " _
& "WHERE ((([dbo_customer].[id])=" & Me![id].Value & ")) "
```

This is a cartesian product that you filter for customer, but not for task.

So you will get as many records as there are records in `dbo_active_task`.

You need to append your WHERE clause to filter for a single task, if you need this source table.